# Multiple inheritance with no function overriding. Why the ambiguity

Tags: c++, multiple-inheritance

Here are my classes. This is just

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class Base
{
public:
    int var;

    Base(int val) : var(val)
    {}

    void foo()
    {
        cout << "Class Base foo()" << endl;
    }
};

class Derived_A : public Base
{
public:
    Derived_A(int val) : Base(val)
    {}
};

class Derived_B : public Base
{
public:
    Derived_B(int val) : Base(val)
    {}
};

class Derived_AB : public Derived_A, public Derived_B
{
public:
    Derived_AB(int var1, int var2) : Derived_A(var1), Derived_B(var2)
    {}
};

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    Derived_AB ABDerObj(1,2);
    ABDerObj.foo();
    return 0;
}
```

And this gives me a compiler error saying the foo call is ambiguous.

Function foo is not overridden anywhere. I understand there are two instances of class Base because there is no virtual inheritance. So there are two 'var' variables. But I don't understand why the compiler is having ambiguity in foo call. Functions are not instance specific. They are class specific. Why is the compiler giving an error?

I am using Visual Studio 2013.

Thank you.

Comment: That's what `virtual` inheritance was made for in the current standard.

Comment: "Functions are not instance specific" - you're wrong, they are.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The multiple inheritance makes you inherit two times the function foo():  one as part of `Derived_A` and one as part of `Derived_B`, because each of it inherits its own `BaseClass`.

```
BaseClass      BaseClass
    |               |
Derived_A      Derived_A  
     \           /
      \         /
       Derived_AB
```

So the compiler doesn't know if it shall execute it with the data of the `Derived_A` or `Derived_B` subobject.

**Solutions:**

1) You can disambiguate explicitely in every call you make:

```
ABDerObj.Derived_A::foo();  // execute foo() for the Deived_A object
```

2) You can disambiguate explicitely at the class level, by defining a common foo, for example:

```
void foo()
{
    Derived_A::foo();   // you want all the foos called
    Derived_B::foo();
}
```

3) If you want to have only a single `BaseClass` for your `Derived_AB`, then you should make BaseClass a virtual base class for `Derived_A` and `Derived_B`.  Then `Derived_AB` will have only one single `BaseClass` and the call to `foo()` is no longer ambiguous.

```
        BaseClass
       /        \
      /          \
Derived_A      Derived_A  
     \           /
      \         /
       Derived_AB
```

(P.S. in this case, you shall also define a `BaseClass()` initializer for `Dervived_AB.`)

Comment: Thank you. My understanding was that only a single copy of a function exists for each member-function of a class. And the compiler implicitly passes '*this' to every member-function, that is why member-functions can access the instance specific members. Isn't also kind of the reason why can simply do a memcopy of a (POD) object to create a new object?

Comment: @madu Indeed, non-static member functions have an implicit `this` parameter. **There is no such thing as a "copy" of a function.** Functions are not objects.  **Member functions are not data members**, and don't exist inside object instances. `memcpy` deals with raw memory of a POD object, that is the data members of class. You could print out the individual bytes of the representation of some objects, you cannot print a function. A pointer to function is not a pointer to object. You cannot convert a pointer to function to `char*` and use the result as such.

Comment: @madu technically, only a single code of your fonction exists. But when the compiler generates a call to the member function, he provides it the 'this' pointer to the BaseClass object. In your example, unless you´d make it virtual inheritance, there are two different subobjects.

Comment: @Christophe OK. I got it now. There is only one implementation of foo, but there are two different '*this' to pass, as there are two instances of Base class. Thank you. This is what I was confused of.

Answer (score 2):

> Functions are not instance specific. They are class specific.

That is only true for static functions. Suppose I change your implementation of `foo()` to the following:

```
void foo()
{
    cout << "My value is " << var << endl;
}
```

What do you expect `ABDerObj.foo();` to print?

---

Since this is an answer, let me also provide two possible solutions.

If `foo` really is instance-specific (for example, because it uses the class field `var`, you can easily tell the compiler which `Base::foo()` you want to call (the `Derived_A` or the `Derived_B` version) by specifying which one you want to use

```
ABDerObj.Derived_A.foo();      // prints: My value is 1
ABDerObj.Derived_B.foo();      // prints: My value is 2
```

or by just throwing away the other part:

```
((Derived_A) ABDerObj).foo();  // prints: My value is 1
((Derived_B) ABDerObj).foo();  // prints: My value is 2
```

The latter is mostly useful if you have a block of code where you are going to use *only* the `Derived_A` functionality, for example:

```
Derived_A& ABDerObjPartA = ABDerObj;
ABDerObjPartA.foo();
// more code using ABDerObjPartA.
```

On the other hand, if -- to stick with your terminology -- the definition of `foo` really depends on the class and not on the instance, make it `static`:

```
// In Base:
static void foo()
{
    cout << "Class Base foo()" << endl;
}

// in main():
ABDerObj.foo(); // This is now OK
```

What you should *really* be looking into is whether you actually *need* multiple inheritance, especially with the same base class occurring more than once. Often once you start having these disambiguation problems they keep getting worse and a slight redesign of your code will make it much more maintainable.

Comment: Thank you. My understanding was that every non-static member class is passed a '*this' as a parameter by the compiler, that is why you can do "cout << "My value is " << var". So each instance of a class has its own copy of the every member-function?